# Building Android ICS source , getting error 41

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-build

I am using 64 bit Ubuntu 10.04 Machine for building ICS
`android-4.0.1_r1` using the Android Source Link -
http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html .
I am using the `sun-java6-jdk`  instead of Open Jdk, and I think that is
the preferrred one.But after hours of building I am getting this
error.

```
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar]
Error 41
```

I am doing the full-eng build and using sun-jdk6.I think thre might be some error in some java classes which resulted in this , i was not able to capture that, i have given another build and dumped the log in some file , which I will post soon.(not whole but the error part only)

Comment: could you please provide more details about the error? it will help us to help you better.

Comment: reinstalled sun6jdk,removed openjdk but now gtting this error : make: *** [out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/apache-harmony-tests-hostdex_intermediates/classes.dex] Killed make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... make: *** out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-tests-hostdex_intermediates/classes.dex] Killed

Comment: and this : /root/WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: warning: hidden symbol '__dso_handle' in out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtbegin_so.o is referenced by DSO out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/libstlport.so